# Stored procedure in Oracle got executed with Invoker's privilege instead of Owners

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, sql-grant

I have read, "Stored procedures and SQL methods execute with the privileges of their owner, not their current user."

I executed the below steps with Oracle USER - SYSTEM   (in Oracle 11g)

Step 1)Created a procedure that creates a materialized view in schema PROD:

```
create procedure prod.sp_create_mview
is
begin
  execute immediate 'create materialized view prod.XXX...';                         
end;
/
```

Step 2) Executed it:

```
begin
  prod.sp_create_mview;
end;
/
```

MVIEW got created in PROD schema

Question:
1. Privilege to create mview and create table were not granted to user PROD, still MVIEW got created. How it is possible if procedure was executed with OWNER (i.e. PROD) privilege

Comment: How exactly was `PROD` created?  What privileges does it have?  I'd wager that the account does have the `CREATE TABLE` privilege.

Comment: @Justin, PROD has CREATE SESSION privileges. I explicitly revoked RESOURCE and CREATE MVIEW grants from PROD and ran the procedure again from SYSTEM to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Oracle treats functions as having the same permission as their invokers.

To define a function which has the permission of the owner, you need to use `AUTHID DEFINER` when defining the function.

So change to

```
create procedure prod.sp_create_mview
AUTHID DEFINER
is
begin
  execute immediate 'create materialized view prod.XXX...';                         
end;
/
```